# Coleman's paper about non-existence of Goldstone bososns in 2D

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, greens-functions, propagator, classical-field-theory

For a massless scalar field in $D+1$ spacetime dimensions the correlation function is given by $$G(x)=\langle 0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle=\int\frac{d^{D+1}k}{(2\pi)^{(D+1)/2}}\frac{e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}}{k^2-m^2}=\int\frac{d^D\textbf{k}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\int\frac{dk^0}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\frac{e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}}{k^2-m^2}.$$ Hence, for a massless field in 2_D we have, $$G(x)=\langle 0|\phi(x)\phi(0)|0\rangle=\int\frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)}\frac{e^{ik\cdot x}}{k^2}\tag{1}$$

1. How is this expression equivalent to Eqn. (6) in [this](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103859034) reference? I understand that there is a singularity at $k^2=0$ but does the integral vanish for $k^2\neq 0$? If not, how can I use $\delta(k^2)$ in place of $1/k^2$?
2. What is the origin of $\theta(k^0)$ in Eqn. (6), whereas Eqn.(1) above doesn't have it [$\theta(k^0)$ appears when one performs the $k^0$ integral and that is not performed in Eqn.(6)]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrote is the time-ordered correlation function,
$$
\langle0|\color{red}{\mathrm T}\ \phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle\sim\frac{1}{k^2-m^2}
$$

In the reference Coleman does **not** consider the time-ordered function, but
$$
\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle
$$
instead.

To get the expression in Coleman's, use
$$
\phi(x)=\int\widetilde{\mathrm dk}\ a(\boldsymbol k)\mathrm e^{-ikx}+\text{h.c}
$$
where
$$
\widetilde{\mathrm dk}=\delta(k^2-m^2)\Theta(k^0)\ \mathrm dk
$$
is the Lorentz invariant measure on the mass-shell hyperboloid.

Comment: Thanks. I have added an edit section where I've tried to calculate the 2-point function as you suggested. @AFT

Comment: in the second (1) equation there should be no $(2\pi)(2E)$ in the numerator. The reason is that the correct measure is $\frac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol p}{(2\pi)(2E)}$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol p}{(2\pi)^{1/2}(2E)^{1/2}}$. In any case, I reversed the edit because the new question is off-topic (as "check-my-work" question). If you have any more questions, feel free to ask here in a comment (and refer to the edit history if needed).

Comment: Dear @AFT I used $\phi(x)=\int\frac{d\textbf{p}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)(2E)}}(a_pe^{-ip\cdot x}+h.c.)$ to evaluate two-point function (kindly refer to my edit). This is the convention that Coleman himself used in his celebrated QFT notes. And Cheng and Li's book too. This expansion too keeps orthonormality condition Lorentz invariant.

Comment: @SRS ok, then in that convention you have $\langle 0|a_{\boldsymbol p}a^\dagger_{\boldsymbol q}|0\rangle=2\pi\delta(\boldsymbol p-\boldsymbol q)$ (see Peskin and Schroeder's book, page 21, eq 2.29).

Comment: Peskin and Schroeder uses $\int \frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E}}$. They don't use $(2\pi)^{-3/2}$ like me because of a different Fourier transform convention.

Comment: @SRS the factors of $2\pi$ are irrelevant, the only important part is the $E_{\boldsymbol p}$ dependence. In any case, the factors of $2\pi$ agree with Coleman's solution, try to work them out with a little bit of care and patience.

Comment: I have figured out the mistake. Thanks. I carelessly used $|p\rangle=a^\dagger_p|0\rangle$ whereas in my convention $|p\rangle=\sqrt{(2E)}a_p^\dagger|0\rangle$.